# How to create a multi project template in visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, project-template

I followed the [How to: Create Multi-Project Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308.aspx) article to create a template that will generate a solution containing 4 projects. My Root.vstemplate file contains the following

```
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
<TemplateData>
    <Name>Yugasat BeyondAdmin</Name>
    <Description>The Yugasat BeyondAdmin Project Template</Description>
    <Icon>Icon.ico</Icon>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
</TemplateData>
<TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="PresentationLayer">
            PresentationLayer\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="BusinessLogicLayer">
            BusinessLogicLayer\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="BusinessLogicLayerAPI">
            BusinessLogicLayerAPI\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="DataAccessLayer">
            DataAccessLayer\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
    </ProjectCollection>
</TemplateContent>
```

I copied the template to the `[drive]:\Users\[user]\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ProjectTemplates\` folder. The problem is that the template is not listed as a multi project template

[image]

So I can create the individual projects, but not a solution containing all 4 my projects. The content of my template folder looks like

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure that the ".vstemplate" file (for each project) has the same name as the project that it resides in.

i.e Presentation Layer should have a PresentationLayer.vstemplate

Its not necessary to create a VSIX Installer for this but the link has a visual representation of what is expected in the "root.vstemplate".

Also, once this has been completed and your template folder has been copied to ~/My Documents/Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ProjectTemplates\, the option should be found in the "Visual C#" section of Create New Project.

Comment: Thank you. Changing the name of the individual templates from MyTemplate to the proper names seemed to do the trick. Not sure if this has something to do with VS 2013 because it worked in VS  2012.